# "or" in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Script has to check if `OLD_VERSION` is not empty or if it doesn't match some pattern. I tried the below code

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD_VERSION="ABCDEFGHIJKL"
PATTERN="ABC"
if [[ ! "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN" ]] || [[ ! -z "$OLD_VERSION" ]];
then
    echo "Not matched or not null"
else
    echo "matched or null"
fi
```

For the above inputs :

```
 bash -x re.sh
 + OLD_VERSION=ABCDEFGHIJKL
 + PATTERN=ABC
 + [[ ! -z ABCDEFGHIJKL ]]
 + echo 'Not null or doesnot match'
```

I get the below output:

```
Not null or doesnot match
```

and also when I make old_version null, i get Not null or doesnot match, where i expect it to print null.

```
$OLD_VERSION=""

+ PATTERN=ABC
+ OLD_VERSION=
+ [[ ! -z '' ]]
+ [[ ! '' =~ ABC ]]
+ echo 'Not null or doesnot match'
```

I get wrong output. I am getting problem in or. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE :

as suggested by sureshvv , i updated it like :

```
if [[ ! "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN"  && ! -z "${OLD_VERSION}" ]] ;
then
    echo "Not null or doesnot match"
else
    echo "matched or null"
fi
```

Thanks all.

Comment: define `wrong output`

Comment: question updated @amdixon

Comment: May be easier to read if you get rid of the double negative. So you can say if [ -z "$OLD_VERSION" || "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN" ]; then echo null or matched; fi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if [[ ! -z "$OLD_VERSION" && "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN" ]]; then
    echo Matched
else
    echo No match
fi
```

Comment: thanks. But i got "matched" when i make old_version null

Comment: I got desired output when i changed it like " if [[ ! -z "$OLD_VERSION" &&  ! "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN" ]]; then  "

Comment: check if you inverted the order ( answer is opposite echo order to yours )

Answer (score -1):

`||` is handled by command `[[`, so you must put it inside `[[` and `]]`

```
if [[ ! "$OLD_VERSION" =~ "$PATTERN" || ! -z "$OLD_VERSION" ]];
```

Comment: Or it could be used as the bash command failure chain operator.